# Laravel: Eloquent 5 tables in 1 query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a 5 tables and i want this to be in the form of eloquent. How do i combine all tables using the `with()`, or their are other ways to do this.

1. student
2. schedule
3. schedule_student `student_id,schedule_id`
4. activity `schedule_id`
5. scores`student_id`, `activity_id`,`score`

**My Models**

```
//Activity
    public function schedule()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Schedule::class);
    }
    public function students()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Student::class,'scores');
    }

//Student

    public function schedules()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Schedule::class,'schedule_student');
    }
    public function activities()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Activity::class,'scores');
    }

//Schedule
    public function activities()
    {
        return $this->hasmany(Activity::class);
    }
    public function students()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Student::class,'schedule_student');
    }

//Student
    public function student()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Student::class);
    }
    public function activity()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Activity::class);
}
```

How do i combine all 4 tables(except `schedule_student`) so the json will look like from below:

```
schedule[] 
   =>activities[]
         =>students[]
               =>scores[]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nested with relation, try something like :

```
$schedules = Schedule::with('activities', 'students', 'activities.scores')->get();
```

Honestly, I understand nothing to your data model, I think you mixed some titles and models. But in the global idea, you can use nested relations using a dot (`.`).